# Draw linestring programmatically using draw control

Tags: openlayers-2

I want to draw linestring feature programmatically which can be done from draw control of openlayers which can inherit default behavior of draw control that is modification, selection, undo, redo etc

I found one method in openlayers but seems not working for me

```
drawControls.line.drawFeature(geometry)
```